# I want that when I enter input text in the field then update it's value Attribute if all have same class

Tags: jquery, html

I have many inputs in the HTML page. I want that when i enter in the input then update it's value attribute with updated text shown in the input field

```
$("input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
 var changee = $(this).val(); 

$(this).val(changee);
});
```

This is the code which i am using in **jQuery**

```
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue"/>
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue"/>
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue"/>
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue"/>
```

As you can see there are multiple inputs with same class and input type 
I want to update its value attribute with its updated text which i will entered

Comment: Its value *attribute*, are you sure? Eg you'd want to see `<input value="foo" type="number" class="changevalue">`? That's pretty weird to want to do

Comment: User input (ie. text) within the `<input>` ***is the value*** of its `[value]` attribute. Do you mean if one receives data you want all inputs with the same class to have it as well?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, you don't have to set the value to $(this) but rather to all Elements that you want:

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    var changee = $(this).val();

    $('.changevalue').val(changee);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue" />
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue" />
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue" />
<input value="" type="number" class="changevalue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").on("change paste keyup", function() {
$(this).attr('value', $(this).val())
});
```